# AttributeError: 'UgatitSadalinHourglass' object has no attribute 'training'

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network, onnx

trying to export

https://github.com/minivision-ai/photo2cartoon

to onnx using the steps from

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/super_resolution_with_onnxruntime.html

```
args = parse_args()

torch_model = UgatitSadalinHourglass(args)
torch_model.build_model()

random_input = torch.randn(1, 3, 64, 64, dtype=torch.float32)

input_names = ["image"]
output_names = ["image"]

torch.onnx.export(torch_model, random_input, './model.onnx', verbose=False,
input_names=input_names, output_names=output_names,
opset_version=11)

AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
in ()
8 torch.onnx.export(torch_model, random_input, './model.onnx', verbose=False,
9 input_names=input_names, output_names=output_names,
---> 10 opset_version=11)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/onnx/utils.py in select_model_mode_for_export(model, mode)
34 def select_model_mode_for_export(model, mode):
35 if not isinstance(model, torch.jit.ScriptFunction):
---> 36 is_originally_training = model.training
37
38 if mode is None:

AttributeError: 'UgatitSadalinHourglass' object has no attribute 'training'
```